# Custom Alert Dialog Box in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design a custom dialog box with a edit text which takes user input and also I want to design custom layout for dialog can anybody help

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: I have done building dialog but i want to have some coustom UI for my dilog..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

**activity_main.xml**

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDialogValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOpenDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Open Dialog"/>


</LinearLayout>

**custom_dialog.xml**

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Input"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Ok"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private TextView txtDialogValue;
    private Button btnOpenDialog;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtDialogValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDialogValue);

        btnOpenDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpenDialog);

        btnOpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                customDialog(MainActivity.this,"Enter value","Ok",R.layout.custom_dialog,new CustomDialogClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(String input) {
                        txtDialogValue.setText(input);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }


    public void customDialog(final Context context,final String title,final String buttonCaption, final int layoutID,final CustomDialogClickListener target) {

        ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
                dialog.setContentView(layoutID);

                final TextView txtHeader = (TextView) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
                final EditText edtInput = (EditText) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.edtInput);
                final Button btnOk = (Button) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
                txtHeader.setText(title);
                btnOk.setText(buttonCaption);
                btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        target.onClick(edtInput.getText().toString());
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    interface CustomDialogClickListener{
        public void onClick(String input);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one:

  public void dialogBox(){

    Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this.getActivity());
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
    mDialog.show();

   EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_number_custom);
}
```

Create one layout that which you need to be show.